# MS DataGrid (WPF) : How to bind a combobox to a class?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

This might sound like a trivial question, but even here in Stackflow I only have found binding to a simple string collection.

I have a Parent class with two properties Name and Age.

I have a Child class with two properties ChildName and ChildAge.

Within MVVM pattern I am exposing these properties into the ViewModels and additionally I am also adding into the ParentViewModel also an ObservableCollection Children

Therefore the ParentViewModel contains three exposed properties: Name, Age and Children.

```
//Inside ParentViewModel
public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> Children
```

My Window.xaml is bound to the MainViewModel that is exposing a

```
public ObservableCollection<ParentViewModel> Parents { get; set; }
```

The Datagrid is defined like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Children" 
                                        DisplayMemberPath="ChildName" 
                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Children.ChildName}"
                                        SelectedValuePath="ChildName"
                                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Children}"
                                        >

                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

While Name and Age of parents show correctly, I dont see the Children combo box populated.
I am confused and frustrated. Please help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`'s `ItemsSource` property to `Children`.